# Integral identity proof

Tags: polynomials, integration

Hi i need to prove this identity. I've tried induction but i get 
stuck in the n+1 phase, can someone give me an idea on how to approach this? Thanks. 
Pn(x) is a polynomial of the n'th degree.
$ \int Pn(x) {e^{kx}} dx = {e^{kx}}( \frac{1}{k}Pn(x) - \frac{1}{k^2}P'n(x)+...+\frac{(-1)^n}{k^{n+1}}P^{(n)}n(x)) +C$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** (assuming $k$ is nonzero) Use an integration by part to get: $$\int P_n(x)e^{kx}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{k}P_n(x)e^{kx}-\frac{1}{k}\int {P_n}'(x)e^{kx}\mathrm{d}x.$$

Comment: Sure, that's the right way to do it, but i think you can't just say "we'll do it n times and that's it" , I think that induction is required here.

Comment: That seems perfectly fine to me, the above identity holds for all polynomials, so in particular for ${P_n}'$. It is not really an induction.

Comment: Alright, thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is:

In the $n+1$ phase just split the integral up into two integrals by using the fact that $P_{n+1}(x) = a_{n+1}x^{n+1} + Q_n(x)$.  Take care to distribute the $e^{kx}$ correctly.  Then you can apply the induction hypothesis to the integral with $Q_n$ in it and you can evaluate by hand the integral with $a_{n+1}x^{n+1}$ in it.

It might be a little easier/clearer/cleaner if for your induction hypothesis you assume the statement holds for $P_{n+1}(x)$ and then try to show it for $P_n(x)$.

Comment: Sure, i've done that, but i get stuck exactly with the integral with the ax^n+1 *e^kx

Comment: @CodeHoarder Integrate by parts with $u = a_{n+1}x^{n+1}$.  Then you'll get something else you can use the induction hypothesis on.  Actually now that I think about it, it may be better to just do int by parts from the start like in C. Falcon's answer.